# Show entire file in Gitkraken diff window

Tags: git, gitkraken

I'm using Gitkraken and would like the entire file to be shown when taking a look at my changes - or atleast have an option to view the entire file. Currently it chops out "irrelevant" parts of the file.

Is there anyway to do this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The view of File History is not enough?

Comment: @datell it's not what i'm looking for. I want to see all the diff lines to inspect each change, but with the entire file shown. I'll give another example: Sometimes a part of a method/function has changed and then you can only see that part for example, and the rest is hidden.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a `File Blame` feature, accessible by right-clicking the filename of an staged or unstaged file, that shows you the whole file along with info about who changed which line in which commit. It also allows you to show the state of the file for each commit listed on the left.

The feature you are asking for, to view more lines of context in a diff view (like you can set in `gitk`, for example), does not exist AFAIK.

EDIT: As of Version 4.0.0, GK finally allows to view and edit whole files. See [GK Release Notes](https://support.gitkraken.com/release-notes/current).

Comment: It's really bad. It's remind me to continue to do my day-to-day work with the bash.